# Regex for name.surname

Tags: c#, regex

Hi i need regex for string like this: "name.surname".
Example: *abdul.hakar, johny.cash*, etc.

But i need it to find only exactly string like them and need to be case sensitive only to small letters.

From these strings:

```
test1265
mfks*/
jan.vavra
jan...buzik
magnum.*/jan.vavra
Jan.vavra
Jan.Vavra
```

I only need to find "jan.vavra"

Tried it this way:

```
[a-z]*\.[a-z]
```

But sadly thats not working.

[image]

With @Olivier answer i got little bit closer. Still some imperfections with + instead of *?

[image]

Comment: You need a * at end.  The pattern is only ;looking for one letter at end.

Comment: Do not use regexr, it does not support C# regex.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew isnt regex always the same? Im just using it to test if it works properly.

Comment: And also, you must use `+` instead of `*` to match at least one letter.

Comment: @JohnyWave No, regex is never the same. There are dozens of different implementations.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes Can you check edited question? Your answer so far the best. But still some imperfections. Its gonna match the text before it. And the third one have no idea why is it matching.

Comment: @JohnyWave That is because you are trying to get to `/^[a-z]+\.[a-z]+$/gm` in the online regex tester. You are not using the anchors and the `m` flag. You do not need the `m` flag in C#, there are no "flags", there are `RegexOptions`, but you do not even need `RegexOptions.Multiline` because you are most likely to test the strings as separate strings, not a single multiline block of text.

Comment: I added to my answer the code to test the string validity in C#. Again, do not rely on regex testers. `[\s-[\r\n]]` is a valid .NET regex, but it won't work in regexr.

Comment: @JohnyWave: See @WiktorStribiżew's answer. He enclosed the expression in `^ .. $` to make it match from the beginning to the end of the string and also made it work with umlauts and other special lower case letters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```cs
^[a-z]+\.[a-z]+$
```

Or, a **fully Unicode-aware** version:

```cs
^\p{Ll}+\.\p{Ll}+$
```

See the [.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%5cp%7bLl%7d%2b%5c.%5cp%7bLl%7d%2b%5cr%3f%24&i=jan.kavra%0d%0atest1324%0d%0awiktor.stribi%c5%bcew%0d%0a%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80.%d1%81%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%0d%0a%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%ba%d0%b8%24%25%23%0d%0a%5e%5evikky%5e%5e%5e&o=m). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `[a-z]+` - one or more ASCII lowercase letters
- `\p{Ll}+` - one or more Unicode lowercase letters
- `\.` - a dot
- `\p{Ll}+` - one or more Unicode lowercase letters
- `$` - end of string.

In C#:

```cs
var IsValidNameSurname = Regex.IsMatch(text, @"^[a-z]+\.[a-z]+$");
// or
var IsValidNameSurname = Regex.IsMatch(text, @"^\p{Ll}+\.\p{Ll}+$");
```

Also, if your string ends with a `\n` char, `$` will find a match. If it is not expected, use the `\z` anchor instead:

```cs
var IsValidNameSurname = Regex.IsMatch(text, @"^\p{Ll}+\.\p{Ll}+\z");
```

Comment: Or (similar to his current regex) \^[a-z]+\.[a-z]+$\

Comment: @Emanuele, yes but without the leading and trailing "\" (or use the back-tick ` instead)

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes But `[a-z]` only matches ASCII lowercase letters. That is too "narrow".